# Many to Many relation with dependency inversion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, multi-module

I have a multimodule application with two modules:

- department-management
- communication-management

now in my `department-management` i have an entity `Department` and in `communication-management` module i have `MailingGroup` entity.

Also the communication-management depends on department-management module.
Now i want to have bidirectional `ManyToOne` relation between `Department` and `MailingGroup`

```
@Entity
public class Department {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
   List<MailingGroup> mailingGroups;
}


@Entity
public class MailingGroup{

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
   Department department;
}
```

This, of course, is not archiveable the way above, but can i archive this bidirectional relation using interfaces? My initial idea was to solve it like this:

```
public interface MailingGroupProvider {
    Department getDepartment()
}

@Entity
public class Department {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
   List<MailingGroupProvider> mailingGroups;
}


@Entity
public class MailingGroup implements MailingGroupProvider {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
   Department department;
}
```

But it raises questions:

- Is this prefered solution in such cases?
- What methods should my interface provide to be treated as Entity by JPA?
- is this even possible what im trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

First Approach is Perfect: You need to add a Relationship in Both Entity Sides.

departmentid is the foreign key of the mailing group Table. Apply Relationship in both entity sides it will work.

@OneToMany Relationship means u can have one Department can have Many Communication.

Bidirectional means suppose if u do any operation in Communication Management like deleting Communication it will affect on Department Table Also. It will Remove Departmentid matched in the Department Table

Comment: if by `First Approach` you mean first code snippet, it won't work because these entities are in different modules, the question is if the interface approach is a valid solution to multi-module problem